What is the Holy Place where the abomination will stand?
If Jesus said that we are the temple of the Holy Spirit then could it be reasonable to assume we are the Holy place?  Also we are told that if we take the mark of the beast or worship his image we will not be in the lambs book of life.
I ask this because the term "Holy Place" is used and if you presume that it is from the perspective Gods view then what indeed does HE consider "Holy".  We are told to be "holy" as He is Holy. I don't see how a place can be Holy. I understand that when Gods presence was in the temple it became a holy place.  But now Gods Spirit resides in us.  What do you think?

The earthly Temple with the earthly holy place and the holy of holies, where God's presence tabernacled with men, was only ever a picture, a pattern, of the heavenly reality revealed to Moses.
Jesus, in his human body, was the true temple, made without hands; that place where God's presence dwells fully and permanently amongst us.
When we are born again, by grace through faith, God's presence lives in us through Christ, the Living Word. Christ is being formed in us, according to the working of the Spirit, but He is still the true Holy Place.  And we, in Him, are being built up.  There is no happening where we, ourselves, are temples in and of ourselves:  Christ is all, in all.
In the latter chapters of Revelation, the New Jerusalem comes down out of heaven to the Earth. It is said that the city has no Temple but that God and the Lamb are the Temple of it.  It is said that the glory of God enlightens it and that the Lamb is the light.
The Lamb, Jesus Christ, is the manifest glory of God in the temple of humanity; made in His image.  In that place within us, where Christ is supposed to dwell, we may, in rejecting Him, harbor an abomination.

Is not this tied up with “the mystery of iniquity” 2 Thes.2:3-6? None but the elect see that which stands in subtle usurpation of divine things and places. The deception takes over, by the will of man changing the gospel, promoting false evangelism and a false ministry and false versions of the Bible, even changing the names of divine things and works. The very name of Christ, of the Holy Spirit, of the name of God, of the temple of God will be subtly twisted to get humanity in the place of Christ. This has already started to happen surely? To speak of the temple of humanity, made in his image

actually promotes the idea of deifying humanity. The Spirit of Christ only dwells in the elect. Those who reject Christ never had his Spirit. And those who think they do, yet do not, will fall for the last, great, satanic deception that causes an abomination to arise. The man of sin is in the middle of deceiving, to that end; promoting fallen humanity to think of itself as divine and able to stand in the place of Christ. And everywhere humanity is promoted, it is part of Satan’s end-game, to demote God and Christ, so that humanity will stand in place where he wants them, in order to

complete his usurpation. There is massive danger in getting the answer to this important question wrong.

@Anne I appreciate the cautioning.  I'm not suggesting that any but born again believers have the Spirit of Christ.  However, those who do are, corporately (2 Corinthians 6:16, 1 Corinthians 3:16-17) and individually (1 Corinthians 6:15-20) temples of the Living God.  It is, as you suggest, crucial to present these things correctly.

Just thinking through the passage where we are told in Revelation - Anyone who takes the mark of the Beast on the hand or forehead or worships his image will be dammed to the Lake of Fire. if we cannot buy or sell without it then maybe it is a type of currency only given to unbelievers who swear allegiance to the Beast in order to obtain the currency/Mammon.

@Anne   Thank you both for your insightful thoughts. I do believe we are to study the scriptures as a body, as well as individually so that we can get a more complete revelation.  So my next question in this journey of discovery is; Do you think there will be another temple rebuilt in Jerusalem and if so would it truly be considered "the Holy Place?" thinking about it from Gods perspective.  And if not a truly Holy place then what/where is the  "holy Place" the abomination that causes desolation going to stand?  I know the theories, but I always search the scripture to confirm.

@Tess Thank-you too. Just to say that Stack does not encourage Qs where different interpretations of prophecies will pile in. If you check the catalogue of previous Qs, you will see many have been closed for that reason. You may also note that the Qs you propose to post have already been asked. Duplicate Qs are also closed for that reason. This site is not like most others; if you follow its links for how to ask Qs, that will help you frame acceptable Qs. Do persevere!
